# Number of ways to select a target

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways given 8 targets can be shot (one at a time), if no target can be shot until the target (s) below it have been shot ?
>
> [image]

My approach :

${3 \choose 1}$ to select any group and $1$ way to shoot it. Followed by ${3\choose 1}$ to select it again and $1$ way to shoot it. Then I took $4$ cases:

case 1. The middle column was over

case 2. either of the first or third column had taken both shots

case 3. either third/first and middle

case 4 . one of third and one of first

This proved futile as I ended up counting each variation manually. What would be the correct way to solve it ? I'm guessing distribution into groups is used somehow.

the answer is $560$

A similar question of targets exists but it is entirely different in the details.

Comment: The solution is the number of distinct permutations of the letters AAABBCCC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to shoot at the left targets three times, the middle targets twice and the right targets three times. So in some order, we have to fire
$$
LLLMMRRR
$$
As long as we know whether we're firing left, middle or right, we know exactly which target we're aiming at, so an ordering of the above letters is sufficient to describe an order of targets.

There are $\frac{8!}{3!\cdot 2!\cdot 3!}$ ways to order the above letters.